# Can you call a method in a bean from a MuleESB <choice>?

Tags: java, javabeans, mule

I want to be able to do something like the following:

```
<spring:beans>
    <spring:bean id="myBean" class="com.address.myClass"/>
</spring:beans>

<choice>
    <when expression="myBean.myMethod() == true" evaluator="someEvaluator">
        <!-- do some stuff -->
    </when>
</choice>
```

I want to invoke 'some stuff' if "myBean.myMethod()" returns true.

Can this be done?

------ Update ------

David was kind enough to help me to this working solution.  Since its buried in the comments below, I added the solution here:

```
<when expression="muleContext.getRegistry().lookupObject('myBean').myMethod()==true" evaluator="groovy">
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

With Mule 3.3, use MEL:

```
<when expression="#[app.registry.myBean.myMethod()]">
```

With older Mules, use Groovy:

```
<when expression="muleContext.registry.lookupObject('myBean').myMethod()" evaluator="groovy">
```

Comment: I added <choice><when expression...> but this gives me an exception:  org.mule.exception.DefaultSystemExceptionStrategy: Caught exception in Exception Strategy: null
java.lang.NullPointerException

Comment: Wait what Mule version are you using?

Comment: Ah, an old Mule :) Reviewed my response, as MEL came in 3.3.0.

Comment: Ah thanx.  Not entirely out of the woods though.  I'm now getting: org.codehaus.groovy.control.MultipleCompilationErrorsException: startup failed, Script1.groovy: 1: expecting '!', found '[' @ line 1, column 2.

Comment: LOL sorry I was using MEL syntax in Groovy :)

Comment: I got it!  A slight modification to your example David.  Thank-you!   <when expression="muleContext.getRegistry().lookupObject('myBean').myMethod()==true" evaluator="groovy">

Comment: Do you really need `==true`?